# I encountered the following error when using object archiving : "The file “users.archive” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Tags: swift, archive

The detailed exception:

> 2023-11-17 00:20:40.993562+0800 FriendCollege[80762:995113] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000270640> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “users.archive” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/zhouzihao/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EB37A319-C800-4B6E-BF59-B9E3B50548FD/data/Containers/Data/Application/47DB7CC2-464B-4C84-AAFF-B881D5BC100D/Documents/users.archive, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c7ad00 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

My code:

```swift
import UIKit

class UserInfo {
    
    static let userInfo = UserInfo()
    
    var UsersCollection = [User]()
    
    let archiveURL : URL = {
        let docDirs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docDir = docDirs.first!
        return docDir.appendingPathComponent("users.archive", isDirectory: true)
    } ()
    
    
    init() {

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: archiveURL)
            if let sc = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) {
                    UsersCollection = sc as! [User]
            }
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }

    }
    
    func saveUser() {
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: UsersCollection, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            try data.write(to: archiveURL)
            print("successfully save")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In fact I had used the code in another project, roughly similar, except the name of variable. So I don't know why it's not right.

Comment: Your code assumes the file exists. But upon fresh install of the app there is no file yet. It's not created until the first time `saveUser()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that need to be changed:

- When you create the URL, `isDirectory` should be `false`.
- As @HangarRash commented, on first run, the archive file is not yet created.

Here's my proposal:

```swift
class UserInfo {
    
    static let shared = UserInfo()
    
    var usersCollection = [User]()
    
    let archiveURL: URL = {
        let docDirs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docDir = docDirs.first!
        return docDir.appendingPathComponent("users.archive", isDirectory: false)
    } ()
    
    private init() {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: archiveURL)
            if let sc = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) {
                usersCollection = sc as! [User]
            }
        } catch CocoaError.fileReadNoSuchFile {
            print("creating new empty archive file")
            saveUser()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func saveUser() {
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: usersCollection, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            try data.write(to: archiveURL)
            print("successfully save")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Like this, an empty file is created on first run.

---

Unrelated to your issue, note a few things I changed:

I renamed your static variable. This leads to a much cleaner call for your singleton object:

```
let userInfo = UserInfo.shared
```

Adding `private` to the singleton object's initalizer makes sure it can really be only instanciated once.

I renamed `UsersCollection` to `usersCollection`, according to the naming convention in Swift (Instance <-> Type).

Comment: Further suggestions: support secure coding and use a non-deprecated `NSKeyedUnarchiver` method. There's also little reason to call `saveUser` from `init`. Having `usersCollection` default to an empty array should be sufficient. I'd also avoid the use of `as!` in `init`. You have an `if let`. Use an optional cast with the `if let` to be safe.